# How to use CMake RPath for boost.Python

Tags: boost, cmake, rpath

I'm writing a Python extension module in C++ using Boost.Python. However, I
would like to use a newer version of the Boost library than the system
installation offers. This newer version of boost is contained in
`BOOST_ROOT=$HOME/opt/boost/1.55.0`.

Following [this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) guide on how
to use RPath in CMake I came up with the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project("test")
set(PROJECT_DESC "Test Boost.Python")

set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE) 
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

add_definitions(-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)

find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibsNew REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using Boost installation in:")
message(STATUS "  INCLUDE: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "  LIB: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
)

macro(add_python_module _name _srccpp)
    PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(${_name} ${_srccpp})
    target_link_libraries(${_name} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endmacro()

add_python_module(ownership ownership.cpp)
```

Then I run the following commands to build the module

```
mkdir build; cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PATH="$BOOST_ROOT/lib" ..
make
```

The status message after running `cmake` points to the right boost
installation. (The CMake boost module picks up the environment variable
`$BOOST_ROOT`) I.e. the CMake variable `Boost_LIBARIES` points to
`$BOOST_ROOT/lib/libboost_python.so`.

But, if I check which libraries would actually be used, the system libraries
are listed:

```
$ ldd ownership.so
# ...
libboost_python.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_python.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f09abfc1000)
# ...
```

This is version 1.53, even though the status message above explicitely pointed
to 1.55.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get ldd to pick the library in
`$BOOST_ROOT/lib/libboost_python.so.1.55.0`?

Comment: `Following this guide on how to use RPath in CMake` AFAIK it's not necessary in your case. CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH option need if you are building shared library with dependencies in your project. E.g. you build shared library `Foo` which depends on shared library `Boo`. So while building `ldd Foo` will show `build-dir/Boo.so` and while installing your need to change it: `ldd Foo` will show `install/path/Boo.so`. All libraries that you're linking is project's externals, so ldd will output install path always.

Comment: Does `PYTHON_ADD_MODULE` command add libraries to link? May be these libraries depends on `/usr/lib64/libboost_python.so`?

Comment: @ruslo It only adds the python library, not the boost python library.

Comment: @ruslo Concerning your first comment. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. But I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. So, basically, how do I get cmake to let my shared object refer to the right version of boost python?

Comment: `I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.` just rewording wiki link you provide: `If the program links to shared libraries which have been also built in the same project, then the RPATH needs to point to the directories in the build tree when running the executable from the build tree, and it must not point to the build tree anymore once the executable has been installed.`

Comment: `So, basically, how do I get cmake to let my shared object refer to the right version of boost python?` Nothing related to RPATH (at least no need for manual modifications). Generate cmake project with `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` and show the linker options

Comment: Tiny project I've tried: http://pastebin.com/UDyYbQ1d. And results: [standard](http://pastebin.com/fXbvw7DJ) and [custom](http://pastebin.com/GBnN01ZJ). As you can see there is no need to use CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH or something.

Comment: @ruslo Thanks you pointed me in the right direction with all this. It turns out, that the actual reason for CMake not adding boost to the `RPATH` was, that the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` (_not_ `LD_`) contained `$BOOST_ROOT/lib`. Apparently, that makes CMake think, that it should not add this particular path to the RPATH. Do you know of a way of convincing CMake otherwise even if `LIBRARY_PATH` is set?

Comment: +1, I've learned something new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as I already mentioned in commens you don't need to use CMake RPATH-manipulations
options. Example: http://pastebin.com/UDyYbQ1d, output: [standard](http://pastebin.com/fXbvw7DJ) and [custom](http://pastebin.com/GBnN01ZJ)

> Do you know of a way of convincing CMake otherwise even if LIBRARY_PATH is set

This issue is not related to CMake, it's compiler responsibility. Read [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/044790.html) discussion.

#### Solution

You can clear `LIBRARY_PATH` if you set `BOOST_ROOT` variable explicitly. And you can check
environment variable in `CMakeLists.txt` to avoid this problem in future:

```
string(COMPARE NOTEQUAL "$ENV{LIBRARY_PATH}" "" library_path_warning)
if(library_path_warning)
  message(
      WARNING
      "LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is not empty ($ENV{LIBRARY_PATH}) "
      "This may cause dynamic linking errors!"
  )
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's probably true, that simply clearing `LIBARARY_PATH` is the cleanest solution. However, unfortunately, I use LIBRARY_PATH for a few other things, and don't want to change these right now. I found a way to just check if the boost, or python library path is contained in `LIBRARY_PATH`. You can find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/yxt1MA1j).